# Why there is no floating point type smaller in byte-size than 'float' in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point

Hopefully it is the 1st question of its type on SO. C# has 4 integral types:

`byte`: 1 byte

`short`: 2 bytes

`int`: 4 bytes

`long`: 8 bytes

But just two floating point types: `float` and `double`. Why did the creators did not feel a need to come up with a tiny float? There is a Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat) about Minifloats.

Comment: My first guess because such a type doesn't exist in the C family of languages, and they didn't see a need for one. Unfortunately, apart from Eric Lippert, guesses are all you are likely to get.

Comment: As @BradleyDotNET said this is a question well suited for the dev team. Plus, the first para of the Wiki page you linked sort of answers the question: _Predictably, they are not well suited for general-purpose numerical calculations. They are used for special purposes, most often in computer graphics, where iterations are small and precision has aesthetic effects._ The .NET world isn't really focused on graphics, so maybe they felt it's not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

To provide an attempt at answer -

Most floating point value systems are based on the IEEE 754 standard; the systems need to be standardized so that hardware manufacturers can provide interchangeable hardware-based implementations of the formats. So, for starters, you're not going to find an implementation unless it is standardized, and the smallest format that IEEE 754 defines is binary16.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory

binary16 is smaller than the smallest type that C# provides, so we're still left with "why doesn't C# implement binary16?".

The answer is likely a combination of reasons:

- C# designers might have felt that it would be an uncommonly-used type (most other languages don't implement it, after all), and providing support for an unused type would be an unwise choice.
- C# designers might have felt that it would add complication that they would've rather not had to deal with when it came time to implement C# on other platforms, such as ARM.

Additionally, the most common platforms that C# would ostensibly run on - x86-32/64 and ARM - don't have much hardware support for binary16, or didn't have any for a long while (see [F16c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F16C)).

Finally, it looks like the folks behind .Net/C# are indeed considering adding support for it, along with other types like binary128:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17267

The software development landscape has changed a lot since C# was created, 18 years ago. Nowadays, we are starting to run a lot more code on GPUs, where we do in fact find and use binary16 types. However, when C# was first created, that might not have been seen as a viable use case. Now that C#-on-GPU is becoming bigger and more viable, it makes sense that the language designers would re-evaluate the design and evolve as the language's use evolve's. And it seems that they're doing exactly that.